# preventDefault, stopPropagation, and cancelBubble not enough to prevent contextMenu from trying to open in Firefox mobile test view

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, firefox

If you open the [test URL](https://p43p5.csb.app/) in Firefox desktop version 91.0.2 (Latest at the time) Windows 10 64-bit (Probably other versions too) and open the F12 menu, then click the Responsive Design Mode button (ctrl+shift+m... Aka the mobile view button) and hold left click to the left of the image, you'll see the number go up to about 25 - then stop and reset to zero, and trigger onCancel. My theory is that's how long it takes until the context menu is normally triggered.

If you try it in regular desktop view or Chrome's regular desktop view - it works as expected - it counts up to 100 (And beyond) until you let go, then onFinish gets triggered.

The full code is here: [Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-perlman-p43p5?file=/public/index.html&resolutionWidth=896&resolutionHeight=675)

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener(
        "contextmenu",
        function (e) {
          // do something here...
          e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
          e.cancelBubble = true;
          return false;
        },
        false
      );

      const noContext = document.getElementById("ItemImage");

      noContext.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        return false;
      });

      function absorbEvent_(event) {
        var e = event;
        e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        return false;
      }

      function preventLongPressMenu(node) {
        node.ontouchstart = absorbEvent_;
        node.ontouchmove = absorbEvent_;
        node.ontouchend = absorbEvent_;
        node.ontouchcancel = absorbEvent_;
      }

      function init() {
        preventLongPressMenu(document.getElementById("ItemImage"));
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      /* https://www.arungudelli.com/tutorial/css/disable-text-selection-in-html-using-user-select-css-property/ */
      .disable-select {
        user-select: none; /* supported by Chrome and Opera */
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
        -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
        -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```js
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";

import "./styles.css";
import { useLongPress } from "use-long-press";
import Item from "./Item";

function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const progressTimer = useRef();
  function handleTime() {
    setProgress((prevState) => (prevState += 5));
  }

  const callback = useCallback((event) => {
    event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation && event.stopPropagation();
    event.cancelBubble = true;
    console.log("long pressed!");
  }, []);

  const longPressEvent = useLongPress(callback, {
    onStart: (event) => {
      console.log("On Start");
      event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation && event.stopPropagation();
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      progressTimer.current = setInterval(handleTime, 100);
    },
    onFinish: (event) => {
      console.log("On finish");
      event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation && event.stopPropagation();
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      setProgress(0);
      clearInterval(progressTimer.current);
    },
    onCancel: (event) => {
      console.log("On cancel");
      event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation && event.stopPropagation();
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      setProgress(0);
      clearInterval(progressTimer.current);
    },
    threshold: 2000,
    captureEvent: true,
    cancelOnMovement: false,
    detect: "both"
  });

  let content = (
    <div className="content-center">
      {progress}
      <Item
        events={longPressEvent}
        name="name"
        image="file.png"
        progress={progress}
      />
    </div>
  );

  return <React.Fragment>{content}</React.Fragment>;
}

export default App;
```

Item.js

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Item.css";
import VerticalProgress from "./VerticalProgress";
import faker from "faker";

export default function Item(props) {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center w-full disable-select">
      <div
        className="float-left absolute z-50 w-full disable-select"
        style={{ height: 500 }}
        {...props.events}
      >
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <VerticalProgress className="z-0" progress={props.progress} />
      <img
        className="z-0 disable-select"
        src={faker.image.image()}
        alt={props.name}
        height="200"
        id="ItemImage"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**My question is:** How can I prevent onCancel from being called early in Firefox desktop mobile test mode? If it's happening there, it's bound to be happening in other browsers like Safari or actual Firefox mobile. Even if it isn't, this is a very much unintended side effect and is making testing mobile difficult.

**Second question:** What's causing the

> IndexSizeError: Selection.getRangeAt: 0 is out of range

Errors?

Comment: Same test, same platform, your code. No issues here

Comment: Do you have any plugin or mouse extension?

Comment: Are you using responsive mode? I have mine set to Galaxy S9 and in a private window with no plugins or extensions it still happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug on the emulator side. On mobile, it works properly.

### TL;DR

The issue seems related to the `Touch emulation` (it happens for any screen size/device). When enabled, fired events changes from `onMouseDown`/`onMouseStart` to `onTouchStart`/`onTouchEnd`, and their behavior changes too. By default, after a fraction of a second Firefox opens the context menu (you can test the default behavior on the 'Open Sandbox' button), This will end the touch and fire the `onTouchEnd` (and also an `onMouseMove`).

*Strange: Whatever I've attempted will not prevent the touch to end (but will prevent the menu to show).*

This being said, I've tested your code on mobile devices (Firefox 91.4.0 on Android - 3 devices - 2 vendors) and everything **works properly**. [This is my code](https://nyqip.csb.app/)

From my observations, there is no context menu on mobile devices, except for few elements like `<img>` or `<a>` which have their own menu (copy link) that I've never been able to remove. But in any case (even when the pop-up menu appears) `useLongPress` works as intended.

#### Notes

Do not mix Frameworks like React and raw DOM functions (like `addEventListener()`). The code you've added in `index.html` does not work as you expect. Do things like this:

```
const __absorb = useCallback((event) => {
  event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();
  ...
  return false;
}, []);

<a onContextMenu={__absorb}>
```